# Production build (--prod) removing decorators/classes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been working on a dynamic Forms framework, that is designed to be extensible. Elements (such as TextElement - which extends ValueElement) make up the form. They are converted into Angular controls (i.e. FormControl) by "Constructors" and are organised within the form layout by "Orchestrators". The files for the above three items are stored in a "forms" Angular library (ng g lib).

The visual representations/components of the above are created by "Renderers", and the renderers/associated components are stored in a separate library (based on style - e.g. bootstrap-form-renderers).

ElementHandlers (constructors/orchestrators/renderers) specify their handled Element via a Typescript decorator.

```
import {FormElement} from '../../elements/model/form-element';
import {Type} from '@angular/core';
import 'reflect-metadata';

export function ElementHandler<TFormElement extends FormElement>(elementType: Type<TFormElement>): ClassDecorator {
  console.log('Handling for ' + elementType);
  return target => {
    Reflect.defineMetadata('elementType', elementType.name, target.prototype);
  };
}
```

e.g:

```
@ElementHandler(TextElement)
export class TextElementOrchestrator extends FormElementOrchestrator<TextElement> {
}
```

Both of these libraries are imported in the Angular app project.

When using "ng build" (no --prod), the code works well. Each form element is created appropriately - e.g. a text input element is represented by an input box, a tags element is represented by a Material design chips component.

The console code is as shown:

```
TextElement extends forms_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ValueElement"] {
    /**
     * @param {?} id
     * @param {?} title
     * @param {?} value
     */
    constructor(id, title, value) {
        super(id, title);
        this.value = value;
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    friendlyValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

However, when "--prod" is used, everything appears as if a "TextElement", and only an input box is shown.

The console reads as follows:

```
class extends ValueElement{constructor(id,title,value){super(id,title),this.value=[],this.value=value}friendlyValue(){const selectedPredicate=option=>option.selected;return this.options.singleMode?this.value.find(selectedPredicate).value:this.value.filter(selectedPredicate).map(option=>option.value)}}
```

I have my suspicions that either:
1. The decorators are getting stripped in the libraries/Angular app build process, as when attempting to log the "elementType" metadata in the --prod build, it shows as "undefined"
2. The classes are somehow not getting included in the build, hence why the above console readout does not show the class details.

Is there any way I can look into this/change this, whilst still keeping the build optimization in-situ?

Any other things I can look at?

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: May be late and not sure, but did you add "experimentalsDecorators": true in your angular config ?